# XHTML positioning paragraph tags absolute

Tags: xhtml, position, absolute, paragraph

Is it standard practice to position paragraph `<p>` tags absolutely or should the paragraph be first wrapped inside a `<div>` tag with the latter being positioned absolutely thus positioning the child paragraph?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is very rare for a paragraph to be absolutely positioned, so no it is not standard practise.

That said, if you have a single paragraph that you want to position, it would be pointless to wrap it in a div just for that.

The usual guidelines apply: Write the markup that best describes the semantics of the content, then add the minimum amount of additional generic markup (divs, spans) needed to style it the way you want.

It sounds like, in this case, the minimum amount is 'none at all'. So don't add a div.